# Apache 2.4 - remove | delete | uninstall

Tags: apache, uninstallation, apache2.4, uninstallstring

I have been searching the web for quite some time, but I could not found how to  **completely** remove the apache 2.4 .

Using :
Windows 7
c:\apache24\

I've tried all commands, but nothing works.

```
httpd -k shutdown
httpd -k stop
httpd -k uninstall
```

keep getting the same result (for each command) :

```
<OS 5> access is denied.
failed to open the 'Apache2.4' service.
```

notice, that the service still running,
meaning that the apache is still working,
and I get the "It works!" in the *localhost*.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are probably running these commands from terminal without [Administrator privileges](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc947813%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

If `httpd -k uninstall` is not working for whatever reason, you should be able to remove service by `sc` command: [Sc delete](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742045.aspx), other tutorial [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/how-to-delete-a-windows-service-in-vista-or-xp/).

Again, ensure that you run these commands as Administrator.

Answer (score 5):

I've had this sort of problem.

The solution:

```
cmd/powershell
```

run as ADMINISTRATOR!!! :D end! I always forget.....

Notice:
In powershell need to put .\ 
for example:

```
.\httpd -k shutdown
.\httpd -k stop
.\httpd -k uninstall
```

Result:

```
Removing the 'apache2.4' service
The 'Apache2.4' service has been removed successfully.
```

Answer (score 2):

Run the Command Prompt ***as an administrator*** and type:

```
C:\Apache24\bin>httpd -k uninstall
```

Worked in Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

I noticed if you haven't added Apache to your path environment variables(call Apache from any folder/directory). You will have to cd.. to your Apache/bin directory and run
 *.\httpd -k uninstall*  to uninstall. (Remember to run PowerShell as administrator)