# xampp is not starting and not even showing any error

Tags: xampp, controlpanel

[This is the error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIaeX.png)

I have installed latest version of xampp first and then installed previous version.But it is not working now

Comment: we'll need a bit more information than this try looking in the log files try \xampp\apache\logs\error.log.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've Apache server installed explicitly (ie as a separate service). 
Apache server starts while system boot and thus this is preventing XAMPP from starting Apache again. 
So, you either need to stop Apache server on CMD as:

```
cd C:\Apache24\bin
httpd -k -restart
```

Then, restart Apache on XAMPP.

Or, you'll have to uninstall Apache as a service completely as is given in this post: [apache 2.4 - remove | delete | uninstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35112260/apache-2-4-remove-delete-uninstall)